# SQL: Query status based on Timestamp and Code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this table:

```
Timestamp[DateTime]   | Code [Text] 
01-jan-2010 00:00:00  | ABC           
01-jan-2010 02:00:00  | AAA           
01-jan-2010 02:20:00  |               
01-jan-2010 03:00:00  | BBB
```

I'd like to group the entries by Start and Stop times, based on the information that `Code != ''` means `RUNNING` and everything else means `STOPPED`. 
The result would look like this (not repeating `RUNNING` entries until `STOPPED` is found)

```
Timestamp[DateTime]   | Status [Text]
01-jan-2010 00:00:00  | RUNNING       
01-jan-2010 02:20:00  | STOPPED      
01-jan-2010 03:00:00  | RUNNING
```

I tried selecting both types in a single query but I don't think that's quite right as the column names would be the same on both subqueries and it doesn't group the RUNNING entries. What would be the best approach to achieve this result? I believe the current approach is not going to be very helpful to me so any ideas are welcome.

Standard SQL syntax would be best. SQL Server Express also an option.

Current Attempt:

```
SELECT Timestamp, Status
FROM (SELECT Timestamp, 'RUNNING' as Status FROM MyTable WHERE Code != ''),
     (SELECT Timestamp, 'STOPPED' as Status FROM MyTable WHERE Code = '')
```

Comment: can you show your current approach and also tag the dbms involved?

Comment: @vkp sure, I am trying to use subqueries, something like this: SELECT Timestamp, Status FROM (SELECT Timestamp, 'RUNNING' as Status FROM MyTable WHERE Code = ''), (SELECT Timestamp, 'STOPPED' as Status FROM MyTable WHERE Code != ''). As for the DBMS, I'm using a proprietary one and I could use SQL Server Express as well, that's why I'd prefer to use standard SQL Syntax, to be able to test it in multiple DBs.

Comment: hmmm your explanation of stopped and running seems backwards if code != '' means stopped then the only running record would be 2:20.....

Comment: @Matt thanks for pointing this out! Attempt fixed in question.

Comment: @D.Caan I see you made the change in current attempt but hadn't made it in narrative I switched for you.

Comment: @Matt that's embarrassing, my apologies and thank you!

Comment: Can you tag RDBMS?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, I'm currently using a proprietary DBMS, I can also switch to SQL Server if necessary, but preferably I'd like to use Standard SQL Syntax. That's why I hadn't tagged "SQL-Server".

Comment: Is outer apply available in your home grown dbms?

Comment: @Matt, unfortunately not. If it is an issue we can opt to use SQL Server Express. Thanks!

Comment: @D.Caan: `outer apply` is called a "lateral join" in standard SQL - maybe your DBMS supports that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    r.Timestamp
    ,CASE WHEN r.T1Code != '' THEN 'RUNNING' ELSE 'STOPPED' END as Status
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          t1.Timestamp
          ,CAST(COALESCE(t1.Code,'') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as T1Code
          ,(SELECT TOP 1 CAST(COALESCE(t2.Code,'') AS VARCHAR(MAX))
             FROM
                myTable t2
             WHERE
                t2.Timestamp < t1.Timestamp
             ORDER BY
                t2.Timestamp DESC) as T2Code
       FROM
          myTable t1
    ) r
WHERE
    NOT(r.T1Code != '' AND r.T2Code != '')
    OR r.T2Code IS NULL
```

Updated to Allow For Testing Null or Empty string and to take into consideration issue of comparison of text data type.

http://rextester.com/OBWS90094 showing it works

If you really want the reverse meaning of stopped/running when Code is not null or empty then change the following lines:

```
CASE WHEN r.T1Code = '' THEN 'RUNNING' ELSE 'STOPPED' END as Status
```

AND

```
WHERE
   NOT(r.T1Code = '' AND r.T2Code = '')
   OR r.T2Code IS NULL
```

This shows it works: http://rextester.com/KUGW22706

You actually can do it all in one query but it is a little easier to show the logic in a nested query so that I can use a column reference.  If your DBMS supported things like a lateral join/apply and/or LAG/LEAD window functions it would be a bit simpler but you can essentially do the same thing using a correlated sub query in your Column definition.  That sub query gets the code of the previous Timestamp Row.  If both current row code and previous row code != '' THEN it is still running so don't show the record.  But you still need to include the first record so test if t2.Code is null.

Comment: You don't actually need the lateral join ("apply")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know I didn't use one, I was just stating that because he doesn't have outer apply or cross apply he can do it using a correlated subquery.  It was kind of like saying this would be easier if....  I will edit to remove the confusion

Comment: Same thing happened for both examples, it is only returning "Stopped" when I look for NULL values, I guess the Code isn't DBNULL is there a way to verify it? It also doesn't allow me to use the != operator with a Text column. I am using SQL Express for testing.

Comment: @D.Caan so you want to test for Nulls not empty strings or both? because your example showed empty string.  AS for test column you probably just need to cast it to VARCHAR() or first.  Also remember we switched the meaning of stopped and running in this example perhaps we should put them back to what you had and we should use different test data?  What is the null in code really supposed to mean?

Comment: @Matt, Based on the results I believe I'm testing against Empty Strings. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: @D.Caan I added took into account the TEXT column data type issue.  Then I change it up to elminate nulls if it is null and make it an empty string so both null and empty string will be evaluated the same.  I gave you both ways of showing running when code is NOT empty and running when code IS empty.  I tested this in postgres (changing top 1 to LIMIT1), sql-server, and I know ti will work in mysql, and oracle so your proprietary system will probably run this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps and islands problem with a twist:

```
select "timestamp", 
       case 
         when code is null then 'running' 
         else 'stopped' 
       end as status
from (
   select "timestamp", code,
          lag(code) over (order by timestamp) as prev_code
   from mytable
) as t
where prev_code is null or code is null
```

The above is standard ANSI SQL.

Note that I had to put `timestamp` in quotes as that is a reserved word in standard SQL. I am also checking for `null` rather then an empty string in the `code` column.

Here is a running example given your sample data:

http://rextester.com/WWEYP16675

Comment: It is returning only "stopped", I believe the values are not really null then, how can I verify it? I am using SQL Server Express for testing after having migrated the data.

Comment: @D.Caan: then check for an empty string `= ''` instead of `null`

Answer (score 1):

```
select [Timestamp],[status]
from
(
select  [Timestamp]
, lag(Code,1,'') over ( order by [Timestamp] ) lead
,code
,iif(Code ='','STOPPED','RUNNING') [status]
from [Table]) x
where  lead  = '' or code =''
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code.

```
;WITH cte_1
AS
 (SELECT [TimeStamp], code,
          lag(code) over (order by [TimeStamp]) as LCode
   FROM YourTable)
SELECT [TimeStamp],CASE WHEN ISNULL(LCode,'')='' THEN 'RUNNING' ELSE 'STOPPED' END Status
FROM cte_1
 WHERE ISNULL(code,'')='' or ISNULL(LCode,'')=''
```

**Output :**

[image]